# Question regarding derivative couplings in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, feynman-diagrams, interactions, correlation-functions

I have a free massive real scalar with the Lagrangian
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\partial^\mu \phi \partial_\mu \phi - \frac{m^2}{2} \phi^2.
\end{equation}

To this I add the interaction
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_\text{int} = \frac{g}{3!}\phi\partial^\mu\phi \partial_\mu \phi.
\end{equation}

I want the second-order correction to the two-point correlator. My question is that while contracting, say $\phi(x_1)$ of the correlator, I can only contract it with the $\phi(y)$ term of the interaction right? Essentially what I am asking is 'derivative' fields cannot be contracted with 'normal' fields right? So the corresponding Feynman diagram at second order in coupling is just the following

[image]

where $\mu_i$ denotes the derivative w.r.t. $y_i$.

Can someone please confirm this?

Comment: Perhaps you can show precisely what you are calculating. Anyway, any $\phi$ can usually connect with any other $\phi$, derivative or not.

Comment: The external φ can certainly be contracted with a $\partial_\mu \phi$ - the derivative will then act on the propagator Δ.

Comment: If you work out the Feynman rules for that vertex, you'll find it's proportional to $g k_1^\mu k_2^\nu$. $k_1$ will refer to the momentum associated with one of the three lines coming out of the vertex, and $k_2$ will refer to the momentum associated with a different line. You should sum over all possible ways of "hooking up" this vertex to the various propagators in the diagram, which includes cases where $k_1$ or $k_2$ is equal to the external momentum.

Comment: @Andrew So that means I can 'hook' it up with an external propagator also right?

Comment: @flippiefanus I am trying to compute the correction in second order to the two point correlator of bosons with the above coupling.

Comment: @QFTheorist yep